# Django shortcuts.redirect NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

I'm getting `NoReverseMatch` from the below view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def new_room(request):
    label="test"
    return redirect(chat_room, label=label)
    # this didn't work either:
    # return redirect('chat_room', label=label)

def chat_room(request, label):
    ...
```

My **urls.py** looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from messaging import views

app_name="messaging"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.new_room, name='new_room'),
    url(r'^(?P<label>[\w-]{,50})/', views.chat_room, name='chat_room'),
]
```

Going straight to `messaging/test/` will load the page correctly. It's only the redirect that is causing the issue.

Full stacktrace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/new/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['messaging',
 'dal',
 'dal_select2',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',,
 'channels']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\channels\handler.py" in process_exception_by_middleware
  240.             return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "g:\Git\Jam\messaging\views.py" in new_room
  26.     return redirect('chat_room', label=label)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in redirect
  56.     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in resolve_url
  147.         return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /messages/new/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'chat_room' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'label': 'test'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using `namespacing` for your `chat_room` app.

Change to:

```
return redirect('messaging:chat_room', label=label)
```

Check [here for `namespacing`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) and also [here too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names).